# AlarmManager não executa no intervado configurado

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Em um método que registra um `AlarmManager` para executar de 30 em 30 segundos o `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public void play(View view) {

        Log.i("lgg", "Botão: broadPlay");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long intervalo = 30 * 1000;

        Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, tarefaIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                intervalo, tarefaPendingIntent);
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver:

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("lgg", "onReceive " + new Date());
}
```

Mas acompanhando o `Log`, vejo que hora ele executa no intervalo correto, hora não, hora demora 1min ou até mais, etc.

Gostaria de saber porque isso acontece ?

E qual o método os grandes app (por ex. whatsapp) usam para a verificação em tempo real ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir da API 19 todos os alarmes com repetição, como `setRepeating()`, serão inexactos, é o mesmo que usar `setInexactRepeating()`.

Uma solução é usar um dos alarmes sem repetição, como `setExact()` e agendá-lo novamente para o tempo seguinte.