# Rodar serviço mesmo que o app não esteja aberto

Tags: android, services, broadcastreceiver, android-alarmmanager

Estou criando um app de despertador e nos testes gostaria que ele despertasse(nesse exemplo ainda apenas vibra), porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que ele rode em background e por isso não acaba despertando, como posso fazer com que mesmo que o app tenha sido destruido ele continue verificando o tempo e se o horario bater então ele se manifeste, do jeito que o código está vejo dois problemas: ele está esperando um certo gatilho para poder ser ativado e acaba não despertando se a tela estiver em sleep mesmo que o app estiver em aberto, e consequentemente não roda a validação da hora se o app estiver encerrado, apenas instalado como um despertador mesmo:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.rafah.screenstate.LockService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //starting the service Class
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));

   }
}
```

LockService.class

```
public class LockService extends Service {

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
       filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
       filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

       //Calling the BroadCast
       final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }

   //AINDA NÃO SEI PARA QUE SERVE
   public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
       LockService getService(){
           return LockService.this;
       }
   }

}
```

ScreenReceiver.class

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("test", "onReceive Broadcast");

    SimpleDateFormat Dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    Date data_atual = cal.getTime();
    String sysdate  = Dformat.format(data_atual);

    if (sysdate.equals("03/04/2018 22:09:02")){
        //Vibrate test
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(6000);
     }

   }
}
```

O que eu preciso é que ele vibre no horario pré-programado mesmo o app tenha passado pelo estado destroy.

Comment: Veja a resposta do Ramaral neste link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281880/alarmmanager-não-executa-no-intervado-configurado .... as vezes responde sua pergunta.

Comment: Veja esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281750/2541)

Answer (score -2):

Tente colocar esse atributo na sua tag.

```
<service android:name="service" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

Comment: A resposta só deve ser fornecida quando se há certeza que ela resolverá a questão, caso contrário use os comentários....

Comment: Andrey, a menos que você mude a configuração do stackoverflow para que eu possa comentar tendo criado minha conta há 15 minutos, vou postar a resposta mesmo. E a solução funcionou para mim.

Comment: Amigo, a menos que vc leia as normas de utilização do SOpt, fica difícil te ajudar. Não estou te criticando, nem negativei sua resposta, apenas lhe mostrando como atuar aqui no site.  
E não, você não deve usar subterfúgios para dar um comentário se vc ainda não tem permissão para tal. Aprenda a lidar com críticas construtivas...

Comment: Obrigada, foi muito construtivo.